# ActionController::ParameterMissing in Protocol::TrasmissionMeansController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with this code .

This is the controller :

```
def create 
  @mean = TrasmissionMean.new(trasmission_mean_params)
  if @mean.save
    flash[:success] = "Mezzo di Trasmissione #{@mean.description}"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Error #{@mean.errors.full_messages}"
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end

def trasmission_mean_params 
  params.require(:mean).permit(:description)
end
```

I have a problem with this code .

This is the view , with render the form:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <%= form_for @mean, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal" },:url => url_for(:controller => "trasmission_means", :action => "create" ) do |f| %>
      <hr>
      <%= render partial: "form", :locals => { :@mean => @mean, :f => f } %>
      <hr>
      <%= f.submit "Aggiungi", class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right' %>
   <% end %> 
  </div>
</div>
```

the render form :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 4, class: 'form-control ', placeholder: 'Descrizione' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the error . I do not understand where  the problem is

`ActionController::ParameterMissing in Protocol::TrasmissionMeansController#create` 
param is missing or the value is empty: mean

Answer (score 2):

The parameters are based on the class

```
def trasmission_mean_params 
  params.require(:mean).permit(:description)
end
```

Is looking for mean in the params hash but your class is called `TransmissionMean` which means it should be

```
def trasmission_mean_params 
  params.require(:transmission_mean).permit(:description)
end
```

Comment: yes this is an error but now i'm stayng in review code modality  :) and there are other errors